# Android static jni method with first jint argument received wrong value

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have declared a static native method in this way:

`public native static void test(int w, int h);`

And then I declared it in JNI in the way:

`void testJni(JNIEnv* env, jint w, jint h)`

Strangely, the `w` always received a value looks like a pointer, seems the jclass/jobject is passed to the first argument `w`.

Instead if the first argument is not a `jint`, say a `jstring`, things would be working fine.

Can somebody explain why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a little more of your native code? The snippet you posted so far looks like it has an incorrect signature.

Comment: Don't guess. Use the output of `javah`. It is never wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your native declaration is incorrect. The second argument for static method is `jclass`, that corresponds to java class where method is placed.

Java:

```
public native static void test(int w, int h);
```

Native:

```
void testJni(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jint w, jint h)
```

For native instance methods second arg is `jobject`, that corresponds to java's `this`

Java:

```
public native void test(int w, int h);
```

Native:

```
void testJni(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint w, jint h)
```

Comment: Thank you Serhio. Is jclass necessary to declare?

Comment: Absolutely, regardless that it may be unused it is required to declare it. Since JVM expects that it is declared and will pass it. Omitting of it leads to undefined behavior.